# Proving an additive function is sigma additive (Measure Theory)

Tags: mathematical-economics, proof, real-analysis

I'm here to kindly ask u a check about the proof of the following statement: 
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra and $\mu : A \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ and additive function. Then $\mu$ is $\sigma$ additive iff for any sequence $\{A_n\} \subset \mathcal{A} $ such that $A_n \uparrow A \in \mathcal{A}$ we have $\mu(A_n) \uparrow \mu(A)$.

Proof: 
**$(\Rightarrow)$ direction**:
Assumre $\mu$ is $\sigma$ additive s.t. $\mu(\cup_{n = 1}^{\infty}A_n)$ = $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n)$. Take an arbritary sequence $\{A_n\} \subset \mathcal{A}$ s.t. $A_n \uparrow A \in \mathcal{A}$.Hence, $\cup_{n = 1}^{\infty}A_n = A$ so that  $\mu(\cup_{n = 1}^{\infty}A_n) = \mu(A)$. Rewrite $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n)$ as $lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{N} \mu(A_n)$ =   $lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\mu(\cup_{n = 1}^{N} A_n) \text{(by additivity)} = lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \mu(A_n) = \mu(A) \text{(by convergence)}$.

**$(\Leftarrow)$ direction**:
Consider a sequence $ {A_n} \subset \mathcal{F} $ s.t. $A_n \uparrow A$, $A = \cup_{n = 1} ^ {\infty} A_n \in \mathcal{A}, \mu(A) = \mu(\cup_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_n) = lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \mu(\cup_{n = 1}^{N} A_n)$. We need to show that $\mu(\cup_{n = 1} ^ {\infty} A_n) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n) $.

Since $A_n \uparrow A$, then $\cup A_n = A$. Hence, we need to show that $\mu(A) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n)  $ by show that it is both $\geq, \leq$.
But, we know that $\mu(A) = \mu(\cup_{n = 1} ^ {\infty} A_n) \leq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n)$. Moreover, take $B_n = A_n \backslash  \cup_{j<n} A_j$ such that $B_i \cap B_j = \emptyset \forall i \neq j$. But then, since $\{B_n\}$ are pairwise disjoint, we have that $\mu(\cup_{n = 1} ^ {\infty} B_n) = \sum_{n = 1} ^ {\infty} \mu(B_n)$. Now $B_n \subset A_n$ so $\sum_{n = 1} ^ {\infty} \mu(B_n) \leq  \sum_{n = 1} ^ {\infty} \mu(A_n)$. Moreover, $\mu(\cup_{n = 1} ^ {\infty} B_n) =\mu(\cup_{n = 1} ^ {\infty} A_n)$. Hence, $\mu(A) = \mu(\cup_{n = 1} ^ {\infty} A_n) = \mu(\cup_{n = 1} ^ {\infty} B_n)  = \sum_{n = 1} ^ {\infty} \mu(B_n) \leq \sum_{n = 1} ^ {\infty} \mu(A_n) $.

Comment: MichaelGreinecker if these are on topic here it might be a good idea to create a measure-theory tag.

Answer (score 2):

Sigma additivity requires that if you have a countable collection $(B_i)_{i \ge 0}$ of mutually disjoint sets ($B_i \cap B_j = \emptyset$ for $i \ne j$) then:
$$
\sum_{i \ge 0} \mu(B_i) = \mu(\cup_{i \ge 0} B_i).
$$

The sets $A_i$ are nested, hence not mutually disjoint. For the proof, the idea is to construct from these a collection of mutually disjoint sets whose union equals the union of the $A_i$.

($\to$) Let $\mu$ be $\sigma$-additive. Let $(A_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a countable collection of nested sets such that $A_i \uparrow A$.

Iteratively define $B_0 = A_0$ and:
$$
B_n = A_n \setminus A_{n-1}.
$$
Note that $(B_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ are mutually disjoint and that for all $n$, $\cup_{i = 1}^n B_i = A_n$. Also $\cup_{i \ge 0} B_i = \cup_{i \ge 0} A_i = A$.

From $\sigma$-additivity, we have:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mu(A) &= \mu(\cup_{i \ge 0} A_i),\\
& = \mu(\cup_{i \ge 0} B_i),\\
& = \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \mu(B_i),\\
& = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = 0}^n \mu(B_i),\\
& = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_n).
\end{align*}
$$

$(\leftarrow)$. Let $(B_i)_{i \ge 0}$ be a countable collection of mutually disjoint measurable sets. Define for all $n \ge 0$, $A_n = \cup_{0 \le i \le n} B_i$. Note that $A \equiv \cup_{i \ge 0} A_i = \cup_{i \ge 0} B_i$ and that $A_n \uparrow A$.

So:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i \ge 0} \mu(B_i) & = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = 0}^n \mu(B_i),\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_n), \tag{$\mu$ is additive}\\
&= \mu(A),\\
&= \mu(\cup_{i \ge 0} B_i).
\end{align*}
$$
So, $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive.